# Pandas: Aggregate the values of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, aggregate

I have the following data frame:

```
name      pet
----------------
John      ['cat']
Mary      ['cat','dog','bird']
Ann       ['bird','rat']
Dave      ['cow','dog']
```

For each person, the column `pet` is a list of animals. I need to get a final list of all pets (no duplicates):

```
final_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'rat', 'cow']
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this (than e.g. naively looping over the dataframe row by row)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `tolist` function to get a list of all the values, flatten them with `itertools.chain`, and then convert to a `set` to get the unique values:

```
import itertools

dfList = df['pet'].tolist()
final_list = list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dfList)))
```

```
print(final_list)
>>> ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'rat', 'cow']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this in a list comprehension (though @ukemi's method is more elegant):

```
>>> [i for i in set(df.pet.apply(pd.Series).values.flatten().tolist()) if type(i) == str]
['cat', 'bird', 'cow', 'dog', 'rat']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply use pandas and do:

```
df.pet.unique()
```

Comment: This doesn't work with a column that contains lists as its values.